# Is it possible to create column width presets in Gutenberg?

Tags: block-editor, columns

Gutenberg gives you some good choices out of the box but is it possible to add a custom preset? I understand I can change the columns manually but was hoping for a preset to make it easier on the client. My other thought was just manually change the 70/30 one to be more 80/20 in the CSS but again for lack of a better option. Any options as far as adding a preset?

[image: column presets in gutenberg]

Comment: I don't have the time to test it, but [looking through the code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns/variations.js) it should be possible by registering a custom variation for `core/columns` (see [docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/))

Comment: @kero Immensely helpful thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear it works! I'm often a bit disappointed when trying to modify core blocks, nice to see that in this case it is so easily possible :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes looking here's what I did. First I enqueued a javascript file into the block editor.

```php
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'block-editor-styles',  get_template_directory_uri('styles/gutenberg.css'), false, '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'block-editor-scripts', get_template_directory_uri('scripts/gutenberg.js'), array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom' ), time(), true );
});
```

Then I just used this bit of code for adding a column variation.

```js
wp.domReady( function () {
  wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
    'core/columns', {
     name: 'two-columns-two-thirds-one-third-eighty-twenty',
     title: '80/20',
     description: 'Two columns; two-thirds, one-third split',
     icon: '<svg />',
     innerBlocks: [
        ['core/column', { width: '80%' }],
        ['core/column', { width: '20%' }],
     ],
     scope: ['block'],
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Note `asset_path()` is code specific, use `get_template_directory_uri()` to reference a file in your theme, for example. Also, to remove the existing defaults, use `wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation("core/columns", 'two-columns-two-thirds-one-third')` with the names of the default variations found [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns/variations.js).

Comment: Good call thanks! Updated my response to match.